# How to update the current playing item in the listview dynamically with an image android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-service, android-mediaplayer

I have created a playlist with an hidden and the title song for the media player. Trying to make the current playing image in the list item visible or invisible on item click with the below code

```
@Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> list, View view, int pos,
            long arg3) {
         if(currentPosition != -1){
              View last = list.getChildAt(currentPosition); // the last one clicked
            last.findViewById(R.id.play_circle).setVisibility(
                    View.INVISIBLE);  
            }
            view.findViewById(R.id.play_circle).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            currentPosition = pos;

        Intent i = new Intent(this, PlayerActivity.class);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
        startActivity(i);
    }
```

seems it works fine but sometimes its giving a null pointer exception inside the if condition and making the app crash. is there a better way to update the list. also how to dynamically update the list when the song finishes and starts the next song. appreciate the help and thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you share more code? The NullPointerException is most probably due to the `list` variable. How to you get a reference to it? Please note, if something like a screen rotation causes your Activity to be re-created, the "list" reference becomes invalid. You could try substituting `list.getChildAt(...` by `getListView().getChildAt(...`, but I'd be great if you could share more code.

Comment: @"its giving a null pointer exception" please post your Logcat.

Comment: Also, are you sure that the NPE is on the `if` of `onItemClick()`? If you had posted the Logcat it might have been easier to answer your question.